# How to connect mongoDB to python [PROBLEMS WITH URI]

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I host mongoDB on my VPS

When I want to connect to DB I get this error:

`pymongo.errors.InvalidURI: Invalid URI scheme: URI must begin with 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://'`

But my URI:

`mongodb://root:mongoroot123@mydomain.online:2701/`

Username and password id correct

**When I connect to DB via MongoDB Compass it works, but via pymongo - no**.

Comment: Please show the relevant python/pymongo code, especially where the URI is created and used.